# Image picker clash in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using `image_picker: ^0.7.5+2`. And my flutter version is (2.0.5). After I take the photo using the camera the apps will restart. But if I get the photo from the gallery no problem. I have added the CAMERA permission. Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: maybe youre using other package  of images

Comment: @Fatimaayaa nope, I use image_picker  only

Comment: You should be getting some error in the console. If not open a terminal and type `adb logcat` and then use the app. you should see some error text right when the app crashes.

Comment: Wait, you seem to be using a null safe version of image picker, but your flutter is not null safe. Use `image_picker: ^0.6.7+22`

Comment: @NisanthReddy Thank you for your reply. When I change to image_picker: ^0.6.7+22   I get this error:

Because google_maps_flutter >=2.0.2 depends on flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle ^2.0.1 and image_picker >=0.6.3 <0.7.0-nullsafety depends on flutter_plugin_android_lifecycle ^1.0.2, google_maps_flutter >=2.0.2 is incompatible with image_picker >=0.6.3 <0.7.0-nullsafety.

So, because myProject depends on both image_picker ^0.6.7+22 and google_maps_flutter ^2.0.3, version solving failed.
pub get failed

Comment: In that case you have no choice but to migrate your flutter to `sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"` which supports null safety, then you can use `image_picker: ^0.7.5+2` as well `google_maps_flutter: ^2.0.6`